# Sort a Dict by Value when Value is a large Binary Vector

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list made up of individual binary lists of length ~ 500 elements.

```
my_list ={a : [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1....0],b : [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1....0] ...}
```

I would like to sort the binary lists so that lists that are most "alike" in their 0 and 1 placement are closest to each other. When I try a simple sort (as a list or I even tried it as a dataframe) I get the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".  Is there an elegant (i.e., pythonic) way to accomplish this?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to build clusters, using [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). This can be done, but I just want to make sure I have right idea before I start designing a solution

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I wasn't familiar with Hamming Distance but now that I've read up on it you are correct, I basically seek to limit the Hamming Distance between adjacent lists.

Comment: What you are looking for then, is to compute the hamming distance between each pair of entries in your dict, and clustering them based off of some threshold